# Getting error while trying to install TensorFlow with pip from Anaconda

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to install TensorFlow pip package from Anaconda command window but I get error messages like below. I use Window-32 bit.

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow(from version:none)
Error: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.7 and Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

You can't upgrade something you doesnt have installed yet.

Comment: I tried pip install tensorflow, but the same errors.

Comment: try this: pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl

tensorflow isnt fully compatible with python 3.7

Comment: How may I do this? If I simply put pip install storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/… into the command window, I get error Invalid requirement  Thanks

Comment: Finally, I installed whl file. Thank you very much!

Comment: but I get an error when I run some code in Jupiter notebook:   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason for you to use pip instead of conda commands (cf. https://www.anaconda.com/tensorflow-in-anaconda/) for tensorflow installation?

Comment: I get an error after commands: the following packages are not available from current channel : tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try:
Setting up the tensorflow environment with python 3.7

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env python=3.7
```

Then

```
activate tensorflow_env
```

Then install TensorFlow with conda env

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Then you should be able to test it by trying python or python3 into the command prompt and importing tensorflow

If the above doesn't work try `pip3 install tensorflow`

I use python 3.6 and it works well TensorFlow so you can also try that version

Comment: I did, but now I have a problem with numpy  - ImportError: Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['C:\\Users\\Home\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.

Comment: Have you tried conda install -c anaconda numpy ? for numpy

Comment: I think I would run a conda uninstall numpy to get  numpy out of the system then do a conda install numpy. Also do you have multiple python versions in there ?

Comment: I have Python 3.7  and Anaconda installed on my computer.

Comment: Well what are the packages in your environment you can check with conda list and if numpy isn't installed try conda install numpy

Comment: I uninstalled and after that installed numpy many times, but when I run code in Jupiter Notebook, I received the message "Numpy is not found".